# PHP: Get output before script is finished

Tags: php

I have a script named data.php that looks like this:

```
/* do some stuff */
echo $result;
/* do some other stuff (eg database operations) */
```

I need to use the output of data.php in another script but I don't want the caller script to wait until data.php is finished.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the flush() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: No webserver nor web browser involved here. Just passing data from script to script.

Comment: @Daniel flush works on the output stream regardless of context. It doesn't matter if this is a webserver or command-line.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically speaking (writing) one script should output to a stream, and the other should read from the same stream.
A good (and simple) example would be one file writes to a file on HD, the other reads from it. Simplest, but not the best.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be more complicated than I thought. Maybe I could also fork a child process for the remaining stuff...

Comment: NNNnnice, I'm totally doing that... ajax requests that just keep reading the output file. And instead of echo in the main php, we write to that output file... so clever...