# Jquery each loop fails to extract values unless using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I built an each loop to adjust the padding on an image tag that sits on top of the image. However, for some reason, unless I use a setTimeout function, it only gets the values of the first one or two values. With the setTimeout function, it works fine.

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    function imgTagMargin(){
          $.each($('.imgHolder'), function (index, value) {
            var holder_parent = $(value).height();
            $('.imgTag', value).css({"padding-top": holder_parent * 0.4})
            // console.log('div', index, ':',  holder_parent, "for", value);
          });
        }
        setTimeout(imgTagMargin, 200);
});
```

Here's the HTML/Php

```
<?php while ($galleryWorker = $galleryBoss->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <div class="imgHolder">
        <img src="_images/<?php echo $galleryWorker['thumbURL'];?>"
            alt="<?php echo $galleryWorker['imgAlt'];?>"
            data-image-full="_images/<?php echo $galleryWorker['imgURL'] ?>" id="thumbnail">
        <h4 class="imgTag"><?php echo $galleryWorker['imgAlt']; ?></h4>
    </div>
```

I'm using jquery 1.12.1 in Chrome.

Comment: Looks like you should call `imgTagMargin` from window onload event or even document ready one

Comment: My mistake, I did do that, but its not listed in the code. I'll update it.

Comment: its because your php is loading slower than your code is executing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533150/when-does-document-ready-fire . . you may be able to use $.ajaxComplete

Comment: @JFit That article was great, it led to my solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
$(document).ready
```

to

```
$(window).load
```

and now it works fine.